# how to download file from ftp server and play them in android application?

Tags: android

I am making an Application to play videos but i want to place videos on server and download then when application installed and play them in application. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got your problem...look into this answer
make a splash screen in your app that will be your first screen where you will download this video and save to external storage like this.

declare variables in class

```
ProgressDialog progress;
String path;
```

and in onCreate

```
        new LoadUrlData().execute();
```

here is your async class to download video from server url

```
class LoadUrlData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,String>
{

    @Override 
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        progress= ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Downloading !",
                "Please Wait");
    } 
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        downloadFileFromServer();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progress.dismiss();

        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

}
    public void downloadFileFromServer() 
{
    try {
        //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
        //this is the file to be downloaded
        URL url = new URL("server url to download video file");

        //create the new connection
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //set up some things on the connection
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");//or Post
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        //and connect!
        urlConnection.connect();

        //set the path where we want to save the file
        //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
        //sd card.
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
        //which we want to save the file as.
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"videofilename.mp4");
        path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.e("Path of file =", "path ="+file.getAbsolutePath());
        //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //this is the total size of the file
        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        //variable to store total downloaded bytes
        int downloadedSize = 0;

        //create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

        //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 
        {
            //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
            //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe

        }
        //close the output stream when done
        fileOutput.close();

        //catch some possible errors...
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and set flag in above method if file downloaded and show in video view.

```
videoview.setVideoURI(path);
```

i hope this ll help you.

Comment: no sir its bad approach i want to download video when application installed (mean in installation process) while your method will videos every time whenever application is run.......

Comment: ok for this use Broadcast reciever based on filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL); for more info follow this one link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350460/android-broadcastreceiver-on-application-install-uninstall