# How to know which application install

Tags: android

I make an application to alert the user that you install this application successfully when user install application from play store. There is any way to get an information of currently install app.

Comment: see this method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: PackageManager is used to get all the installed applications!

Comment: @Tushar i dont want to already install app i want to know the info new install app info like antivirus which pick currenty launch or install app

Comment: Yes you can do that as well. [See this about how to fetch data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5841353/3531756). And to get the latest application: PackageManager is used to get all the installed applications, then whenever you start the app again run the code and it will get new list, compare the two lists, mismatched apps are new ones.

Comment: how funny. a link to another question is accepted as answer. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17601553/1404734

This will give you application link.

To get details after new application is installed, refer this link:
[Android: BroadcastReceiver on application install / uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350460/android-broadcastreceiver-on-application-install-uninstall)

Answer (score 0):

You can find it by using an application's packagae name. For eg, for Facebook app use the following code:

```
 String applicationPackageName = "com.facebook.katana";
 try{
    ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().
            getApplicationInfo(applicationPackageName, 0 );
    return true;
} catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
    return false;
}
```